# MCU packet capture

Tags: cisco, voip, wireshark, sip, pcap

I am trying to do a packet capture of a video conference hosted with CISCO [Codian] MCU. The instructions for capturing SIP packets with Wireshark are available. I also configured MCU to accept SIP calls.

I have installed X-Lite as a SIP client and set the host to the IP address of my MCU. I configured the softphone to not register with a proxy, and place calls using the same credentials that I use to sign into the MCU.
When I call my conference, it seems to INVITE and ACK go thru. Sorry, I don't know SIP.
Either way, it appears that MCU answers the call and my client is sending video - only I get nothing in return.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my residential ISP was blocking SIP traffic. From my office, everything works fine. Sorry for bothering.

Comment: most probably it's the NAT traversal. I don't believe that an ISP in Czech Republic would block anything. It's happening in Arab countries, but I can guess it's not your case by looking at your name :-)

Comment: @StanislavSinyagin
Port blocking is pretty common in Europe. Wireless do this more than residential, either not rare at all. For example, I know that LycosMobile blocks VPNs. Some Telcos have plans without blocking that cost more... STUN/TURN work fine from my home. Otherwise, I would be screwed capitally. :)